# Is Unicorn useful for "typical" sites?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, unicorn

I have a small site on Heroku and am currently using Thin.
I've been vaguely aware of Unicorn but never felt like I had something that fit its "fast client" stipulation.

The readme and [this](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/everything-you-need-to-know-about-unicorn/) link suggest that we're talking about only using Unicorn on a LAN (or maybe Lambdarail) but it seems like lots of people are using it for typical sites accessed by normal broadband and maybe even mobile networks. Is this true? What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicorn is typically used behind an webserver/proxy like Nginx which receives the HTTP connection from the actual client, serves static assets and forwards dynamic requests to the backend server (Unicorn).

The webserver now acts as a client to Unicorn. Because Nginx (and for most cases Apaches mod_proxy) act as a store-and-forward proxy. I.e. they will first buffer the full response (or at least as much as fits into its buffer) before sending it to the client. And this nicely fits Unicorn's definition of a fast client. It hands the difficult task of caching and serving the data to slow clients to the webservers which have to do it anyway and thus can probably do it much better.

It also suggests that you should probably not run Unicorn directly facing to a client (unless your clients consume the data fast (e.g. on a LAN with non-congested clients and network).

Comment: Fantastic response! Heroku's Cedar HTTP handling seems very lightweight but does anyone know if it significantly buffers requests back and forth?

Answer (score 0):

We're using unicorn on heroku and having good results with it. What the unicorn site doesn't distinguish is that there's a difference between unicorn serving dynamic data vs. static assets. If you are offloading asset serving to a CDN, there's not much difference in unicorn with or without nginx in front. Once caveat to this - raw unicorn is vulnerable to an 'intentionally' slow client, such as might be introduced in a DDoS or other hack attempt.